# how to use the css and images in a bundle?

Tags: symfony

I'm new in symfony2, and I'm confused how to use css and image by asset.
For example, I have a boundle named userbundle, and i put my css and image in UserBundle/Resources/public/css and  UserBundle/Resources/public/image. But by asset, they were located in web/acmeuser/css and web/acmeuser/image. They do not exist and of-course I can not show them.

answer:
The problem is because of the svn. If you have svn in both sides, which means in src/bundles and in web/bundles. If both of them is in svn control, then the command

assets:install web

will cause this exception: 
unlink(web//bundles/framework\images.svn\text-base\open_quote.gif.svn-base): Permission denied in \vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Util\Filesystem.php on line 101 
If you just removed your /web/bundles and set svn ignore to it. rerun the command and all goes well.

Comment: you should add your answer as a SO answer and accept it if you are fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
{% block javascript %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/UserBoundle/Resources/public/css/Filename.css') }}" ></link>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/UserBoundle/Resources/public/js/Filename.js') }}">
</script> 


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: yes, i know, i use command : assets:install web and i got error:


PHP Warning:  unlink(web//bundles/framework\images\.svn\text-base\open_quote.gif.svn-base): 
Permission denied in <workspace>\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Util\Filesystem.php on line 101


and the command just conflict with svn. Is there anyway to ingnor svn or just copy them?

Comment: that's what i have done. It conflict with svn and it can not copy them. I saw some discussions from [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2025). It seems they have already ignored the svn repository, but i always get this error message after running the command:  

    Permission denied in <workspace>\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Util\Filesystem.php on line 101

Comment: ok, the problem is solved.  
Just remove all your svned boundle repository in /web/ and then set svn ignor boudle. rerun the command and all is ok. The ignor option is only ignor the origin source. But if you already have something in web/boundle, that will create confilct.